# Can't copy text from Chrome console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

If I ouput a message to the console:

```
console.debug('This is a line of text');
```

Then try to select the message and copy part of it, I can't do it. I can only select the entire message and even then, I can't copy the message. CTRL+C fails and does not copy the message to the clipboard.

How can I copy a message from the console?

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome 119, which is already fixed in the next version, currently beta. The workaround is to copy via [devtools-on-devtools](/q/12291138). You can also downgrade to 118 via policies.